# How to structure different common code shared with different projects?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a webserver project that works with soap webservices and saves data to db.

Now I'd like to write some importer classes that process build some kind of database cache on a regular basis. These importer classes should reuse lot's of the webserver project (especially the domain leyer, domain POJOs, database services, configs etc). The importers shall later run on a different machine than the webserver, thus independently.

How does a maven/eclipse project have to be structured so that I can separate these two projects, but reuse lots of the common code?

Would I place the classes just both into the same project? Or would I move the common code to a single jar, and create 1 webserver and 1 importer project using this jar as dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last paragraph did give a rational solution.

If the importer and web application is something that is closely related, and the "reusability" for those "common class" is aimed to be within this project only, what you can do is having a multi-module project like this:

```
foo // your project name
  + foo-main    // your reusable classes, you may split it into several modules if appropriate
  + foo-web       // have foo-main as dependency
  + foo-importer  // have foo-main as dependency
  + foo-parent    // my personal preference is to make parent project a module, not mandatory
```

If your importer is something irrelevant to your foo project, but you still want to reuse, you can split it out

```
foo // your project name
  + foo-main    // your reusable classes, you may split it into several modules if appropriate
  + foo-web       // have foo-main as dependency
  + foo-parent    // my personal preference is to make parent project a module, not mandatory

bar-importer  // another project, having foo-main as dependency
```

or even make that common code a separate project

```
app-common   // the common code in original foo-main, 
             // maybe a multi-module project


foo // your project name
  + foo-main    // foo-specific codes, have app-common as dependency
  + foo-web       // have foo-main as dependency

bar-importer   // having app-common as dependency
```

For Eclipse, there should be nothing to worry about.  Given you are using latest Eclipse + M2E plugin (should already been bundled with latest Eclipse), if you have correct POM, when you are importing the projects to Eclipse (by Import -> Existing Maven Project), relationships between projects should already been created.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed answer. One more question concerning the first approach: the importer will in a way be related as it has to import cached data to DB that is then used by the main/web application. That's why I want to reuse at least the domain classes. Anyhow, the main app will not make any reference to the importer java classes. Having this: would you go for the first approach where everything is within one multi module project? Or would you take the importer completely out?

Comment: The main thing to consider is that multi-module project bounds "development lifecycle" of its modules together. If you want to release projects independently, then I would say the second approach is better.

Comment: what told by Pavel Horal is also the main concern in my mind. (and that's why my "importer and web application are closely related" means)